# c# unsafe access to fixed memory throws AccessViolationException randomly in release mode

Tags: c#, access-violation, unsafe

I have come across a AccessViolationException randomly when trying to access a memory block via unsafe pointers, but **only when compiling in release mode** (with code optimization). The debugger is attached but will ignore any break point. For testing purposes, I just call the same function in a loop with the same arguments and eventually the exception is thrown. Without code optimization, it works correctly. **The memory block is assummed to be fixed** as if I try to make the pointer fixed, the compiler complains that "You cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression". The memory block is allocated by a external libraries. The code is something like:

```
 public static void TestFunct(ImageObj FloatImage)
    {
      try
      {
       unsafe
       {
        int memSize;

        //EDIT: Missing the local copy of the image object
        ImageObj FloatImageLocalCopy = FloatImage.CopyImage(); /*This local copy
 will not be explicitly used after the call of GetFloatMemPointer()*/


        IntPtr memHandle = FloatImageLocalCopy.GetFloatMemPointer(out memSize); /*Dll function 
                     that returns a pointer to a float memory block*/

        float * myPtr = (float *)memHandle;

       //fixed(float * myPtr2 = &myPtr[0]) {} /* I tried several ways to make the
                 pointer fixed but compiler won't let me as it is already fixed*/ 

        float val;
        for(int i=0; i<memSize; i++)
        { 
         val=myPtr[i]; //throws the accessViolationException sometimes!
        }    
       }
     }
     catch{}
    }
```

Then I test the function until it breaks;

```
//...
    while(true)
     {
       //GC.Collect(); Thread.Sleep(5); 
/*If I fire the GC before the 
 function, exception is not  thrown (or at least it becomes very unlikely), 
 but I cannot afford to use it like this in 
 the real application*/

       TestFunct(myImage);
     }      
    //...
```

I have the impresion that it only breaks if the GC is collecting while loop is running but if the mem block is fixed it shouldn't be a problem, right? So, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

### **EDIT:**

I forgot an important detail; I was not indexing the input *FloatImage* itseft but a local copy using *.CopyImage()* (just added).

**PROBLEM FOUND**
It turns out that when the code optimization applies, local objects can be collected even before reaching the end of its scope, if the GC thinks that they are elegible for collection as they are not used anymore. More info in: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193 and [When EXACTLY is an object eligible for garbage collection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874344/when-exactly-is-an-object-eligible-for-garbage-collection-in-c)

In my case (as pointed out in the answers), the problem comes from the external libraries. The image object is fixed but they that are not providing a way of linking the lifetime of the object to the lifetime of its pointer. Thus, the GC is sometimes collecting the image while still in the unsafe loop, as the copy of the image is not used again after the call of GetFloatMemPointer().

**WORKAROUND**
To keep the object alive until the end of the functions it is enough to call **GC.KeepAlive(** *FloatImageLocalCopy* **);** or a dummy method of the object like *int memSize = FloatImageLocalCopy.GetImageSize();* after the unsafe block

Comment: Without knowing whether the external library is doing it's job *correctly*, nor whether your code is making safe *assumptions* about what it's doing with the returned values, it's going to be nigh impossible for anyone to assist here.

Comment: So I fear, but part of my question is that, if the compiler sais that the mem block is fixed, can it still be moved by the GC under any circumstances?

Comment: No, by casting an `IntPtr` to a `float *`, *you* told the compiler "trust me, this is a pointer to a fixed block".

Comment: Once you're in `unsafe` territory, the compiler trusts what *you* tell it. You could equally have done `float * myPtr = (float *)((IntPtr)0x00010005);` and the compiler would thank you very much and almost certainly throw an AV when you try and do anything via the pointer.

Comment: Ok, then how can I pin the memory underneath from the IntPtr with "fixed"?is it possible in any way?(I tried but not succedded)

Comment: You cannot. You're on the wrong side of the hatch. That was a job that was properly the responsibility of `GetFloatMemPointer`, if it's promised (in documentation) to give you a fixed buffer. From this side, all we have is a pointer. We have no guarantee that it's even a pointer *to the start of some managed object on the heap*. It may be an interior pointer of some kind.

Comment: (We also have to trust that library to have correctly reported `memSize`, which could also lead to AVs if it turns out that you're dropping off the end of what's actually allocated and you're unlucky enough to hit a page boundary)

Comment: Yes, it's kind of an act of faith for me. Let's assume for a moment that the pointer really points to a managed mem block. Could I fix it in that case before the (float*) casting?

Comment: The GC cannot and does not collect or move unmanaged memory, that's not your problem. There is no need to "fix" that memory because it's already "fixed" -- by virtue of there being no process that moves it. (The reason for pinning memory is to pass it to unmanaged code. There is never any need to pin managed memory that's processed by managed code.) Check if you're interpreting `memSize` correctly -- is it the size in *bytes* or the size in *floats*? You're treating it as the latter.

Comment: Provided that it works in debug mode everytime and most of the times in release mode, always with the same input data, it makes difficult for me to believe that the problem comes from a wrong _memSize_ interpretation,( I still don't discard any possibility). I tend to think, as Damien pointed out, that it could be a problem in the external code. However I want to be sure before casting the first stone.

Comment: Bear in mind that one of the things that can be *most different* between debug and release are *the patterns of memory allocation*. And it may just be that it can happen under debug but would be far *rarer*.

Answer (score -1):

Im going to assume windows?

why not do this

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
            private static extern void CopyMemory_Win32(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint size);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlCopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
            private static extern void CopyMemory_Win64(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint size);

    float[] Data=new float[memsize]
    var hnd = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr ptr = hnd.AddrOfPinnedObject();
//Get Size in bytes a float is 4 bytes long.
    CopyMemory_Win64(memHandle,ptr,memsize*4);
    hnd.Free();
```

Now you can access said data the normal way 
Data[0] etc

Comment: [`CopyMemory` is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016390/4137916). Use `RtlMoveMemory` if [`Buffer.MemoryCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.buffer.memorycopy) is not available.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it exists but only in 32bit version of windows (before 10). i have tested both on many machines and they are reliable. RtlCopyMemory tho is only 64bit why both are here. maybe using a libc.dll from lgpl works would be more relyable.
As Buffer.MemoryCopy is not CLS-compliant.

Comment: If, between the external code passing a pointer back to the calling code and the calling code trying to access the full range of the implied buffer, something is happening that causes an AV, it's highly likely that `CopyMemory_Win64` will now also trigger an AV. Why do you think the copy will be able to access the "full" range safely when the original code cannot?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever AV i never came across this. do you mean accessviolation. Ive not had that yet in code like this. when copying 44100 bytes from libsndfile to a managed buffer and altering it.